# Python 3- cut peptide regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.3

Aim is to code the theoretical tryptic cleavage of protein sequences in Python. The cleavage (cutting) rule for trypsin is: after R or K, but not before P. (i.e. the trypsin cleaves (cuts) the protein sequence after each K or R, unless (K or R) is followed by a P).

This is my regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('[KR]?[^P].*?[KR](?!P)')
peptides = pattern.findall('GGRGAGSAAWSAAVRYLTMMSSLYQT')
```

output:

```
GGR and GAGSAAWSAAVR
```

What i would like is:

```
GGR and GAGSAAWSAAVR and YLTMMSSLYQT
```

Findall is returning only the ones that were cut and not the remaining.
Thanks

Comment: Your pattern requires a `K` or an `R` as the last character. Naturally it cannot find any further matches after the last `R` (as there is no `K`). You might want to explain a bit more about the logic behind this.

Comment: Please describe in English what the rule should be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168727/trypsin-digest-cleavage-does-not-work-using-regular-expression

Comment: In proteomics there are certain rules where a peptide is cut. The above link explains the rules. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the link you posted

> The cleavage rule for trypsin is: after R or K, but not before P. (i.e. the trypsin cleaves (cuts) the protein sequence after each K or R, unless (K or R) is followed by a P).

This could be implemented as follows:

1. Match a character.
2. Before matching the next character, check that the last one was not one of the splitting `K` or `R` (which is not followed by `P`).
3. Then consume that next character.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3.

In regex this would look like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r".(?:(?<![KR](?!P)).)*", 'GGRGAGRPSAAWKSAAVRYLTMMSKPSLYQT')
['GGR', 'GAGRPSAAWK', 'SAAVR', 'YLTMMSKPSLYQT']
```

(I have no clue whether this is a valid sequence, but it includes all relevant cases.)

Answer (score 3):

*In silico* cleavage of peptides/proteins is a typical task and has already been implemented. For example, you can use [`pyteomics`](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/) (which I develop) in the following manner:

```
In [1]: from pyteomics.parser import cleave, expasy_rules

In [2]: cleave('GGRGAGSAAWSAAVRYLTMMSSLYQT', expasy_rules['trypsin'])
Out[2]: {'GAGSAAWSAAVR', 'GGR', 'YLTMMSSLYQT'}
```

As you can see, popular cleavage rules are already coded in. But you can provide your own:

```
In [3]: cleave('GGRGAGSAAWSAAVRYLTMMSSLYQT', '[KR]?[^P].*?[KR](?!P)')
Out[3]: {'GAGSAAWSAAVR', 'GGR', 'YLTMMSSLYQT'}
```

Here is [the relevant section in the tutorial](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html#sequence-operations).

If you are interested in how it is currently implemented, take a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/levitsky/pyteomics/src/44cb2d32955d79677fad526ecfb37e89e7674353/pyteomics/parser.py?at=default#cl-463):

```
@memoize()
def cleave(sequence, rule, missed_cleavages=0, overlap=False):
    """
    Docstring omitted here for brevity.    
    """
    peptides = set()
    cleavage_sites = deque([0], maxlen=missed_cleavages+2)
    for i in chain(map(lambda x: x.end(), re.finditer(rule, sequence)),
                   [None]):
        cleavage_sites.append(i)
        for j in range(0, len(cleavage_sites)-1):
            peptides.add(sequence[cleavage_sites[j]:cleavage_sites[-1]])
        if overlap and i not in {0, None}:
            peptides.update(
                    cleave(sequence[i:], rule, missed_cleavages, overlap))

    if '' in peptides:
        peptides.remove('')
    return peptides
```

Comment: I was going to use this and I know about this package but the problem is numpy installation which is giving me error so i cannot use this package.

Comment: @user2669020 I would suggest solving the `numpy` problem once and saving you time in the future :) You can start by searching for the error message you get. You can also ask a new question about installing `numpy`, which would also be on-topic for this site.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very better way to solve your problem, and the simplest also:

```
peptideo=""
proteina=raw_input("Digite a sequencia da proteina a ser digerida: ")
i=0
for i in range (0,len(proteina)):
    peptideo=peptideo+proteina[i]
    if (proteina[i]==("R") and not (proteina[i+1]=="P")):
        print "Peptideo digerido", peptideo
        peptideo=""
    if (proteina[i]==("P") and not (proteina[i+1]=="P")):
        print "Peptideo digerido", peptideo
        peptideo=""
print "Peptideo digerido", peptideo
```