# Tryptic peptides from protein sequence using python

Tags: python, string, position, substring, character

I am just starting with Python and got many helpful advices from Stack Overflow. I have a protein sequence and can determine by enumerate the positions of K and R in the sequence.
For example:

```
def character_indexes_comprehension ():
    match1 = "R"
    match2 = "K"
    
    return [index for index, character in enumerate(seq1, 0) if character == match1 or character == match2]
print (character_indexes_comprehension())

or

print ([pos for pos, char in enumerate(seq1) if char == "K" or char == "R"])

or

xpos = ([pos for pos, char in enumerate(seq1) if char == "K" or char == "R"])
print ("Liste xpos", xpos)
```

All give me the positions of K and R in the sequence. I also want to include missed cleavages, meaning going from a position of K and R to the second and third K or R in the string, how to do this. Now I want to extract the peptides between the amino acids next after K or R until including next K or R. For these peptides I also want to calculate the molecular weight and later the isotope distribution. The calculation of the molecular weight works for the protein and I need to transfer to the peptides. I have the position but how to extract the numbers from the list/array? Sorry if it is easy, I am a newcomer
Thanks a lot
Manfred

Comment: You should add a sample input and expected output to make it easier to understand your requirements.

Comment: Say you had XXXXKXXRXXXRXXXKXXX, would you eant to extract the start and end of the sequence (XXXXK, KXXX) which are not in-between a K or R?

Comment: @manrai, on a slightly tangential note, I think you'll find the [Biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation) package very useful basics operations on protein sequences.

Comment: @manrai, I've also just found a specific R package, [cleaver](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/cleaver/inst/doc/cleaver.html), that performs cleavage operations for a range of enzymes.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers, I know BioPython as an "easy" way, but we want students to program this to understand it.

Comment: @manrai check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168727/trypsin-digest-cleavage-does-not-work-using-regular-expression) where they use regex.

Comment: Many thanks, I used for the sequence:

Comment: Many thanks, I used for the sequence the fasta file of human albumin and I used the regex: protein = re.sub(r'(?<=[RK])(?=[^P])','\n', seq1) and it works fine, gives me all peptides I want to see. But I can see only the sequences after print(protein). I need to calculate the molecular weight based on the sequence, and I am lost, help needed how to do this.Many thanks ahead